# How to copy a FrameworkElement including the overflowed content?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bitmap, drawing

I'm using some code that I found at http://brianlagunas.com/wpf-copy-uielement-as-image-to-clipboard/ to copy a rendered XAML Treeview. The treeview is configured for scrolling if the content overflows the available height.

```
const long DPI = 96;
FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)param;
double height = element.ActualHeight;
double width = element.ActualWidth;
RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Math.Round(width), (int)Math.Round(height), DPI, DPI, PixelFormats.Default);
DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
{
    VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(element);
    dc.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(), new Size(width, height)));
}
bmp.Render(dv);

DataObject _data = new DataObject();
_data.SetImage(bmp);
```

That works fine when my content fits inside the client area:

[image: Treeview when client area is large enough to avoid overflow]

But it's problematic when the content overflows the client area:

[image: Treeview when client area is too small and overflow occurs]

Is there a way that I can get the entire control content *without* having to resize the onscreen element?

**Edit:**
Here's the Treeview XAML:

```
    <TreeView x:Name="ProjectTree" Grid.Row="1"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ShinyTreeView}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              MouseDoubleClick="TreeView_OnMouseDoubleClick"
              Style="{StaticResource CodeExplorerTreeViewStyle}" BorderThickness="0,1"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <controls:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TreeView>
```

And the button that binds the treeview to the button's command:

```
            <Button Command="{Binding CopyResultsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ProjectTree}">
                <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/document-copy.png" />
                <Button.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeExplorer_CopyToolTip}" />
                </Button.ToolTip>
            </Button>
```

Comment: I don't know if this would do the trick or not, but have you tried setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on the TreeView control?

Comment: That might be forcing all nodes to render (although my sample Treeview is very small, so I can't see any difference), but it doesn't seem to change the rendered bmp.

Comment: If `param` is the `TreeView` control you want to draw it works correctly. Maybe you are passing the `ScrollViewer` control to the function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm passing the Treeview (I've added the XAML elements as edits to the original question. Maybe there's something about the ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: One way could be to temporarily put the control in a container with infinite size (such as `Canvas`)

Answer (score 1):

I did some experimentation with your code. The problem appears to be that you're using `element.ActualHeight` and  `element.ActualWidth` to construct the bitmap, which of course is equal to the current size of the TreeView control (not the content panel which is actually longer), so that's what you get rendered in the output.

What I did to fix the problem was to set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled` for the `TreeView` and then wrap it inside a `ScrollViewer`. This will make your `TreeView` full-height that it requires and still having a scrollbar to scroll through it. Now when you construct your bitmap using ActualWidth and ActualHeight, you get a full-size bitmap and rendering it gives the desired result.